# select2 duplicated in iziModal

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I use iziModal for my modal, but select2 select box is not clickable in modal,

i added the following code after initializing modal:

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#myIziModal')
        });
```

but now select box is duplicated and one of the select boxes is working fine but the other is not clickable

modal code:

```
<div id="myIziModal" style="display: none;">
    <select class="select mySelect2" style="width: 150px;">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
function showModal() {
        $("#myIziModal").iziModal({
            title: "info",
        });
        $("#myIziModal").iziModal('open');

        $('.mySelect2').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#myIziModal')
        });
    }
```

note: when i use `$('.Select2').select2({ dropdownParent: $('#myIziModal') });` select box is not duplicated and is clickable but do not display any options.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DvNS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select element must have a class with name `select2`. so if you use another class name for the select element you have to changed it(only the select element that is in the modal).

```
<div id="myIziModal">
    <select id="mySelect2" class="select2">
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
function showModal() {
        $("#myIziModal").iziModal();
        $("#myIziModal").iziModal('open');

        $('#mySelect2').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#myIziModal')
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because You are using ID(id="mySelect2),
Please Use class for define select 2

Like this
`$('.mySelect2').select2({ dropdownParent: $('#myIziModal') });`

and use in class property any where in the code
Like this
`<div id="myIziModal" style="display: none;"> <select class="select mySelect2" style="width: 150px;"> <option value="1">one</option> <option value="3">two</option> <option value="5">three</option> </select> </div>`

Comment: question updated after testing your solution. please read again.